# Preventing session expiration if user active

Tags: php, session

I have mini content management sytem with basic login system. I wonder, how to prevent session expiration if user active for ex. typing content or something else? Is there any way to do it?
 How can i rearm the session every time an interaction takes place?

Comment: You may want to add some sort of event listener on the page.  When some interaction event occurs (e.g. focus changes, page scrolls, characters typed, etc.), you would send an ajax request to a `ping`-type page on your server.  In the php page you can "re-arm" your session.

Comment: I have autosubmit function that posts form data to php in every 30 sec let's say. How to reset/extend session time in every for ex. db query (in PHP)?

Comment: If you already contacting the server every short period of time, then calling `session_start()` in your PHP should be enough.  As long as the interval between calls is less than the `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting in your php.ini, you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to attach an event handler to some user interaction event, such as mouse movement, or keyup, or something similar. On the event you could request something from the server using ajax.  This would then keep the session alive.

Comment: I have autosubmit function that posts form data to php in every 30 sec let's say. How to reset/extend session time in every for ex. db query (in PHP)?

Comment: Which ever php page your form submits to just have session_start() at the top of it and that should renew the session timeout.  If it appears not to, then perhaps something else is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have an event listener listen to any user interaction event and have it call a simple PHP page with a session activity [Example: `session_start()`].

But be extra cautious when listening to mousemove event, as it may choke your server by giving a lot of consequent AJAX requests. You could attach a timer and control the frequency of calls made.